# Zoom button has been missed on my google map today! (Openlayers, Geoext)

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I had a map which overlays Google street map plus some WMSs. It was working till yesterday, but, suddenly today I can see the map, but zoom button is missed! I am using Google map API v2, Openlayaers and Geoext APIs. My code is:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
            var options = {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                units: "m",
                numZoomLevels: 18,
                maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34)
            };
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);

            var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Streets",
                { isBaseLayer: true, numZoomLevels: 20, sphericalMercator: true }
            );
            map.addLayer(gmap);

            var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Satellite",
                { type: G_SATELLITE_MAP, 'sphericalMercator': true, numZoomLevels: 20 }
            );
            map.addLayer(gsat);


            var mappanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
                region: "center",


                map: map,
                title: 'Map Layers on Google'
            });


            var layerList = new GeoExt.tree.LayerContainer({
                text: 'Map Layers',
                layerStroe: mappanel.layers,
                leaf: false,
                expanded: true
            });

            var layerTree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
                title: 'Map Layers',
                maxWidth: 500,
                Width: 300,
                region: "west",
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                root: layerList,
                 split:true
            });

            var descriptionPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                title: 'Metadata Description',
                Width: 400,
                region: "east",
                contentEl: "description",
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: false,
                split:true
            });

            var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                height: 800,
                renderTo: "mainpanel",
                layout: "border",
                items: [mappanel, layerTree, descriptionPanel]
            });
```

Is there anybody here who could let me know what happened when everything was working! 
By the way, I received an email by google couple of days ago that google map v2 is has expired and will be down next month! Maybe they shutdown it earlier!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to Google Map API v2. As soon as I switched to using v3, this problem solved.

Here in Openlayers example, the same problem is observable.
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google.html

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. Nobody knows what has changed on API v2? With V3 it's all OK http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3.html

Comment: Rather than posting an answer as "having the same problem", just monitor the page for a solution.

Comment: You could switch to Google map API v3 and your problem will be solved. This is what I did for my V2 map API since it is going to be shutdown soon in end of November I guess.